# Which R8 rules are necessary to make an android app with a libgdx game work once published in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, proguard, android-r8

I am trying to publish an android app that includes a libgdx minigame, it works fine after appliying R8 (minifyEnabled true) in debug mode, but when I do it in release mode and publish it in the Play Store, the app crashes when I press the button that opens the libgdx game. I use Android Studio version 4.0

I have tryed several times with different R8 rules, but none of them works when on production.

My code in the Android Module:

build.gradle(:android)

```
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true 
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild




#-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers
# tried changing AndroidControllers with line:
-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.*

# tried adding this one
#-keep class com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher  

#    -keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {
#       <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
#    }

# tried separating AndroidInputs
    -keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput {
       <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
    }
    -keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInputThreePlus {
       <init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context, java.lang.Object, com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
    }

# tried with this
-keepclassmembers class com.ongngo.game.CoreAndroidInterface
-keepclassmembers class com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.**
-dontnote com.badlogic.gdx.**
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Cubemap* { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL* { *; }
#


-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
onCreate(...) 
        ...
        coreAndroidInterface = object : CoreAndroidInterface {
            override fun updateLifes(lifes: Int) {
                var lifesVar = lifes
                if (lifes < 0) {
                    lifesVar = 0
                }

                MainActivity.LIFES = lifesVar
                prefs.lifes = lifesVar
            }
        }
```

a Button in a fragment (depending of MainActivity) starts AndroidLauncher.k:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        config.useAccelerometer = false
        config.useCompass = false
        initialize(MyGame(MainActivity.LIFES!!, MainActivity.coreAndroidInterface), config)
    }
}
```

Code in the Core module:

CoreAndroidInterface.kt

```
interface CoreAndroidInterface {
    fun updateLifes(lifes : Int)
}
```

MyGame.java

```
public class MyGame extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
private final CoreAndroidInterface coreAndroidInterface;
...
    public MyGame(int vidas, CoreAndroidInterface coreAndroidInterface) {//constructor
        this.LIFES = lifes;
        this.coreAndroidInterface = coreAndroidInterface;
    }
```

The errors I get from the Google Play Console when the app crashes are:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher.onCreate
```

Type:
java.lang.RuntimeException

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2795)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2873)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1602)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6543)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInputFactory.newAndroidInput (AndroidInputFactory.java:65)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init (AndroidApplication.java:34)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize (AndroidApplication.java:1)
  at com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher.onCreate (AndroidLauncher.java:36)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7023)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7014)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1215)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2748)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2873)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1602)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6543)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at java.lang.Class.classForName (Class.java)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:378)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInputFactory.newAndroidInput (AndroidInputFactory.java:8)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init (AndroidApplication.java:34)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize (AndroidApplication.java:1)
  at com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher.onCreate (AndroidLauncher.java:36)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7023)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7014)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1215)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2748)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2873)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1602)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6543)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at java.lang.Class.classForName (Class.java)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:378)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInputFactory.newAndroidInput (AndroidInputFactory.java:8)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init (AndroidApplication.java:34)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize (AndroidApplication.java:1)
  at com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher.onCreate (AndroidLauncher.java:36)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7023)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7014)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1215)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2748)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2873)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1602)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6543)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [issue for this exact problem](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5785) on the issue tracker. Either you update to libgdx 1.9.11, or you should disable R8 until you do. You can use Proguard instead.

Comment: I had libgdx version 1.9.8, updating it to 1.9.11 solved the problem. @MrStahlgelge solution fixed my problem.